# Create dataframe that contains all columns not present in two other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I tried to find rows from the dataframe `df1` that do not exist in another dataframe `df2`.

The columns of df1 are `FIRSTOCCURRENCE_IPCORE,IDENTIFIER, Order_IPCORE`

The columns of df2 are `FIRSTOCCURRENCE_IPCORE,IDENTIFIER_x, Order_IPCORE`

The output (`df3`) should contain the columns `df1` has but that are missing in `df2`

This is my attempt:

```py
df3 = df1.loc[df1.merge(
    df2,
    left_on=[ 'FIRSTOCCURRENCE_IPCORE','IDENTIFIER', 'Order_IPCORE'],
    right_on=['FIRSTOCCURRENCE_IPCORE', 'IDENTIFIER_x', 'Order_IPCORE'],
    how='left',
    indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left_only"').index]
```

The code threw this error:

```
KeyError: [1699, 1700, 1703, 1709, 1710, 1711, 1714, 1715, 1716, 1720, 1721, 1722, 1723, 1726, 1730, 1731, 1732, 1733, 1734, 1735, 1736, 1737, 1738, 1739, 1740, 1741, 1742, 1743, 1744, 1745, 1747, 1748, 1749, 1750, 1752, 1753, 1755, 1757, 1758, 1760, 1761, 1762, 1763, 1764, 1765, 1766, 1767, 1768, 1769, 1770, 1771, 1772, 1773, 1774, 1775, 1776, 1777, 1778, 1779, 1780, 1781, 1783, 1784, 1785, 1786, 1787, 1788, 1789, 1790, 1791, 1792, 1793, 1794, 1795, 1796, 1797, 1798, 1799] not in index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
mcols = ["FIRSTOCCURRENCE_IPCORE", "IDENTIFIER", "Order_IPCORE"]

df3 = (df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={"IDENTIFIER_x": "IDENTIFIER"}),
                 on=mcols, how="left", indicator=True).query("_merge == 'left_only'")
           [df1.columns]
)
```